# A simple tidy up needed in regex

Tags: r, regex

I have had a good morning of trying to tidy this up but cannot find a more elegant solution.

I have the following as a value:

```
TEST <- Pia1.2016-10-08.1103+N2353.tif
```

and from this I need the date and the time 'extracted', I have the following (which works but I am 100% sure there is a better way to do it)

```
DATEDIR <- sub("[P][i][a][1]\\.","",TEST)
DATEDIR <- sub("\\...............","", DATEDIR)
DATEDIR                                               # to check
```

I have not got round ot extracting the time bit yet as I thought I would clear this up first, although I would like the time variable to be called

```
TIMEDIR <-
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Try something like https://ideone.com/M8viib

Comment: Hero! Cheers I will answer it

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
TEST <- 'Pia1.2016-10-08.1103+N2353_hc.tif'
date <- sub('.*?\\.(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\..*', '\\1', TEST)
time <- sub('.*?\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\.(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).*', '\\1:\\2', TEST)
# => [1] "2016-10-08"
#    [1] "11:03"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/M8viib). See the [Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/EhXuju/1) and [Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/EhXuju/2).

The first pattern matches

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possilbe
- `\\.` - a dot
- `(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})` - Capturing group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 2 digits
- `\\.` - a `.`
- `.*` - any  0+ chars, as many as possilbe.

The second pattern matches and captures the subsequent two digits into Group 1 and the next two digits into Group 2, and the `\1:\2` replacement formats the time into a `HH:mm` string.

Comment: Great, the explanation really makes a big difference! Many thanks